# python convert tuple to dict by using key list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

My sample tuple list looks like this.

```
[ 
   ( 
      '179981',
      'multi_city_vicinity',
      'Venice',
      'IT',
      '12.338332',
      '45.434032',
      '6022967',
      None,
      '[{"id":"6049644","type":"province_state"}, 
      {"id":"6048725","type":"province_state"},
      {"id":"86","type":"country"},            
      {"id":"6022967","type":"continent"}]',
      '{type=Polygon, coordinates=[[[11.976222, 45.461517], [11.980149, 
        45.453074], [12.02615, 45.447188], ....... [11.990328, 45.473449], 
        [11.983233, 45.474886], [11.976222, 45.461517]]]}'
      ),
     ...
   ]
```

i want to change

using this list.

```
key_list = ["region_id", "region_type", "region_name", "country_code", "center_longitude", "center_latitude", "continent", "geometry", "ancestors", "coordinates"]
```

I want this dict list

```
[
     {
      "region_id": ’179981',
      "region_type": ’multi_city_vicinity',
      "region_name": 'Venice',
      "country_code": 'IT',
      "center_longitude": '12.338332',
      "center_latitude": '45.434032',
      "continent": '6022967',
      "geometry": None,
      "ancestors": '[{"id":"6049644","type":"province_state"}, 
      {"id":"6048725","type":"province_state"},
      {"id":"86","type":"country"},            
      {"id":"6022967","type":"continent"}]',
      "coordinates": {"type": Polygon, "coordinates": [[[11.976222, 
        45.461517],[11.983233, 45.474886], [11.976222, 45.461517]]]}
      }, 
      ...

]
```

> I don't have a sense of what to do. How can I replace a tuple list with a dict list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension and `dict(zip(...))` to change all tuples to dictionaries:

```py
dict_list = [dict(zip(key_list, tup)) for tup in tuple_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `dict(zip(...))`:

```
tuple2 = [dict(zip(key_list, tuple1[0]))]
```